# How to get ID of 3rd Previous Input Type Time Once Button is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, identity

I have got the following inputs like so:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='time' id='32'>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='text'>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='time'>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='time' >
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class='clicker'>Get ID</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I click the button I want Jquery or JS to alert me the ID in the 3rd previous input (where `type=time`), which is `32`.

I have tried the following code:

```
alert($(this).prev('input[type=time]').prev('input[type=time]').prev('input[type=time]').attr('id'));
```

However, I keep getting `undefined`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `prev()` gets the children in a node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```js
$('.clicker').click(function() {
    alert($(this)
        .closest('tr')
        .prev('tr')
        .find('input[type=time]').attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='time' id='32'></td>
        <td><input type='text'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='time'></td>
        <td><input type='time'></td>
        <td><button class='clicker'>Get ID</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `id` like this. `prev()` gets the previous siblings in a node, which is not your case.

```
$(this)
  .closest('tr').prev() //get the parent tr, then call prev() to get above tr
  .find('td:first input').attr('id');
```